# Delete last added specific symbol, on keydown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well i have a input field and i want to delete dash (-) if someone write it. This is my code:

```
$( "#ownerEntrance" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
    var value = $( "#ownerEntrance" ).val();
    if (event.type=="keydown" && event.which == '189') { // 189 for - symbol
        $( "#ownerEntrance" ).val(value.substr(0, value.length - 1));
    }
});
```

But now it delete symbol before dash. Can i fix it? Thank you!

Comment: try out onchange or onkeyup

Comment: onchange doesn't work, onkeyup is correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `replace` with this regex `/(-)/g` on `keyup` event:

```js
$('#no-dash').on('keyup', function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  
  $this.val($this.val().replace(/(-)/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="no-dash">
```

This will remove all dashes even on paste(by keyboard). You can add `change` event to remove it in any ways.

Comment: keyup is a key here :)